# Angular 4 httpclient mapping observable to nested json

Tags: json, angular, observable

With the help of the forum I was able to get my httpclient observable mapping issue sorted with this syntax;

```
this._http.get<DomainMetaData>(serviceURL);
```

which works great! However, I have a json response coming back from the server which is nested and wonder if I can use the same syntax as I'm currently using or if I need to now manually .map the response into my classes?

Based on posts I've seen here on SO I've created two classes to represent the nested structure of the response JSON (see below).

The function call...

```
  getDomainMetaData(domain): Observable<DomainMetaData> {

    let serviceURL = "http://localhost:3000/selectdomains?domain=" + domain;

    return this._http.get<DomainMetaData>(serviceURL);

  }
```

The classes...

```
export class DomainMetaDataAttr {
  constructor(public name: string,
              public value: string) {
  }

}

export class DomainMetaData {
  constructor(public name: string,
              public attributes: DomainMetaDataAttr[]) {
  }
}
```

An example of the json...

```
//DomainMetaData
// {
//   "ResponseMetadata": {
//      "RequestId": "11f000bf-0dff-8a2a-31ff-8631a9f25b5b",
//      "BoxUsage": "0.0008183545"
//   },
//   "Items": [
//      {
//         "Name": "2",
//         "Attributes": [
//            {
//               "Name": "Document Date",
//               "Value": "22/03/13"
//            },
//            {
//               "Name": "Document Ref",
//               "Value": "Doc test"
//            }
//         ]
//      },
```

I love the neatness and simplicity of my current solution but I appreciate I may now have to change my code!

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to know how to use the JSON response from an HttpClient call.

I currently approach it like this:

```
// x.service.ts
getData() {
    return this.http.get(URL);
  }

// x.component.ts
this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
        if (res['data']) {
          const data = res['data'];
          // do whatever with the data 
        }
      });
```

With the above approach you can run whatever methods / filters you want on the JSON e.g. map over the array and pull data out / mutate it, etc. Not sure if it's necessary to create additional classes to deal with the nested JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Oops! The code I posted actually works, I just wasn't referencing the results in the attributes array correctly.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.